# Is it mandatory for $F$ to be divergence free to have surface independent property?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals

I was trying to solve the problem to find $\int_{C}F\cdot dr$ where $C$ is the curve of intersection of cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and plane $z=1$. Also $F(x,y,z)=y\vec{i}+z\vec{j}+x\vec{k}$ 
[image]

So here we have two possible surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ with same boundary $C$ oriented positively.

I tried verifying for above $F$ which is divergence free and successfully showed that $$\iint_{S1}\text{curl}(F) \cdot dS_1=\iint_{S_2}\text{curl}(F)\cdot dS_2$$

But in this link: 
https://mathinsight.org/stokes_theorem_examples

they have taken $F=\left(\sin x-\frac{y^3}{3}, \cos y+\frac{x^3}{3}, xyz\right)$ and its been told that
$$\iint_{S_1}\text{curl}(F)\cdot dS_1=\iint_{S_2}\text{curl}(F)\cdot dS_2$$

any clarification?

Comment: i corrected it by editing the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field $F$ in your first example is "by coincidence" divergence free. This has no avail for the line integral $\int_C F\cdot dr$.

By Stokes' theorem this line integral is equal to the surface integral $\int_S{\rm curl}(F)\cdot dS$ for *any* surface $S$ with $\partial S=C$, in particular for the two surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$ in your figures:
$$\int_{\partial S} F\cdot dr=\int_S{\rm curl}(F)\cdot dS\ .$$ 
There is no divergence appearing here.

On the other hand the *curl of any field* $F$ is divergence free: $${\rm div}\,{\rm curl}(F)\equiv0\ .$$ This plays a rôle in your second example: The two surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$ together bound a three-dimensional cone $K$, whereby $\partial K=S_1-S_2$. By Gauss' theorem we therefore have
$$\int_{S_1}{\rm curl}(F)\cdot dS-\int_{S_2}{\rm curl}(F)\cdot dS=\int_{\partial K}{\rm curl}(F)\cdot dS=\int_K {\rm div}\,{\rm curl}(F)\>dV=0\ .$$